# dropdownlist to select the html page to be sent as mail body

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, dropdown

I have made a mailer where I want to send a html page as the mail body. Here is the code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        SendHTMLMail();
    }

    void SendHTMLMail()
    {
        MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();

        Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtUsername.Text);

        Msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text);
        Msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        Msg.Body = myString.ToString();
        Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        if (fuAttachment.HasFile)
        {
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName);

            Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fuAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream, FileName));
        }

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtpwd.Text);
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(Msg);
        Msg = null;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email sent.');", true);
    }
}
```

I have certain html pages in my app data folder. Now what I want is a dropdown from which I can select the html page that I send as the mail body. How can I populate the dropdown to select among those html pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am not sure about which platform you are trying to do that. So, I am going to write a generic approach.
In order to read the files and its content from the `App_Data` folder you need to first get the path of the `App_Data`:

> For web application

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/App_Data"));
```

> For windows application

```
string projectFolder = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).FullName;
string folderAppData = Path.Combine(projectFolder, "App_Data");
```

Now to get all the files from the `App_Data` folder use this function which will return a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`

> For web application:

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getFiles()
{            
     DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/App_Data"));
     var fi = di.EnumerateFiles("*.html", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
     var files = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
     foreach (FileInfo file in fi)
     {
       files.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(file.Name, file.FullName));
     }
     return files;
}
```

> For windows application:

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getFiles()
{
   string projectFolder = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).FullName;
   string folderAppData = Path.Combine(projectFolder, "App_Data");
   var diw = new DirectoryInfo(folderAppData);
   var fiw = diw.EnumerateFiles("*.html", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
   var filesw = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
   foreach (FileInfo file in fiw)
   {
      filesw.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(file.Name, file.FullName));
   }
   return filesw;
}
```

Now with this function, you will get data in the format of a key-value pair as:

```
     Key    |    value
file1.html  |  c://somefolder/App_Data/file1.html
..... other files
```

Now you can use this list to populate the data in the `dropdown` where the `key` object is the file name which you can use as the `text` field and `value` object is the file path which you can use as the `value` field.

And now to read the file contents you have to pass the file path got from the function declared above by passing the file path:

```
public string getFileContent(string path)
{
   return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
}
```

> Binding for webForms:

in the Page_load() event just add these lines

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    var list = getFileNames();
    ddl.DataSource = list;
    ddl.DataTextField = "Key";
    ddl.DataValueField = "Value";
    ddl.DataBind();
}
```

**Note**: for a better approach it is advisable to create a separate class to handle the files. Whereas in production don't store the file path on the client side (in HTML) instead of this, store the file path in the database and give the id of the file as the value for the dropdown than on your mail send just get the file path from the DB and then get the content.

Comment: how can i bind it in the dropdown

Comment: which platform are you using windows or web?

Comment: i am using web platform

Comment: i just want show the html pages that are there in app data in the dropdown and choose one among them to be sent as mail body

Comment: @harsha once you get the `list` of files just bind it to your `dropdown` object as `ddl.DataSource = myList;` and then set the DataTextField as `ddl.DataTextField="Key";` and DataValueFiled as `ddl.DataValueFiled = "Value";` Here the `DataTextField` is the one that displays the name of the HTML page and the `DataValueFiled` will contains the path of the file.

Comment: how can i get the list?

Comment: on your  `Page_Load` event just call the function `getFiles()` pass it to a variable as: `var list = getFiles(); ` then bind the list to the object of your `DropDownList` on which you want to show the data.

Comment: i have done the same but dropdown is not showing anything and the getfile function is showing a count=0 on debugging

Comment: got the key value pair in getfile function but not gettinh anything in dropdown

Comment: @harsha ok, let me check and are you calling the `ddl.DataBind()` after setting the data source as the list.

Comment: it would be of great help

Comment: @harsha check the answer I have updated it with binding.

Comment: thank you so much you saved me from getting nostalgic as was trying this since long. :)

Comment: can you help me with one more thing?     Now what I want is, based on the page selected from drop-down, I want to replace certain links in that html page. There can be any number of links and i don't know about them. What I am concerned about is:

I want to replace each link with my corresponding links
I want to know which link was clicked and send the link as a query variable on another page
Also link can be in any form i.e- http/https/www

Comment: @harsha you can do that by creating a mapping table of links with respect to the `HTML` page and on your pages you can have something like `{0} {1} {2}` and then you can replace the `{0}` like values with the links from the mapping table by using the [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: i m trying to do something like this to replace the links with my link but unable to do -                                                                                                  
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dd1.SelectedItem.Value);
                string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
                string output ;
                output = readFile;

Comment: Regex regx = new Regex("http(s)?://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*([a-zA-Z0-9\\?\\#\\=\\/]){1})?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                MatchCollection matches = regx.Matches(output);

                foreach (Match match in matches)
                {
                    output = output.Replace(@"match.Value", @"http://localhost:61187/two?" + "sender=" + Server.UrlEncode(this.txtUsername.Text) + "&reciever=" + output);
                }

Comment: @harsha my suggestion would be to go for the Mapping table but you can post a second question asking about the link replacement logic and add your code of what you have done so far, as I don't have much understanding of `regex`.